# Is title of 'My Map View' automatically used in mapKit?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, mapkit

[image]

When coding an app I found for a tutorial on using the MapKit facility on iphone, when running the app simulator, I find the title of the app called 'My Map View'.

I did a search on the words and it came up with nothing in the code workspace. Is this because the title is automatically shown as this from the Mapkit framework? Can I change it? How would I get to the code piece?

Also, I had a look at the nib file, and because the app has been fully programatically coded in the map, there is no nav bars etc. Everything has been hardcoded in, which doesn't help me at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found that if I go into the 'MainWindow.xib' and double click on navigation controller option, the Root View Controller nib pops up which has what i am looking for - the title bar!

Cheers